# clickhouse & javascript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, clickhouse

i am reading 100M with 2 columns only numbers. Records are  chunked by 1000. After 7M records application crash on garbage collection heap out of memory. I changed driver to mysql and read same 100M records and it get finished allright.

I used @makeomatic/clickhouse and @apla/clickhouse and it getting same error. In same case when i read 25m records from diffrent table, that seems to work allright and memory doesnt getting grow up. How i should inspect garbage memory leak? Is possible that clickhouse is using http response and that getting read into memory and not getting properly streamed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it depends on used javascript driver


try use simple streaming wrapper on nodejs for HTTP interface
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/http